# How to match centering of RelativeLayout (centerInParent) and layer-list (gravity:center) as windowBackground?

Tags: android, android-layout, centering

I have created windowBackground using layer-list, where i center item (bitmap) by using `android:gravity="center"`. Then i show same image, but using Relative Layout with ImageView and it is centered using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. However image in relative layout is slightly higher. How to center them, so they are at same position?

Layer list as windowBackground in splash_background file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/appBackground" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@raw/splash_animated" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Activity with this Relative layout (using the style below):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LaunchAnimatedActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@raw/splash_animated" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullscreenSplash" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this piece of code to align background image with activity image:

```
val statusBar = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
if (statusBar != 0) {
    //getting statusbar height
    val statusBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(statusBar)
    val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.splash_image)
    // using FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout
    imageView.updateLayoutParams<FrameLayout.LayoutParams>
    {
        //orientation aware
        if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            leftMargin = statusBarHeight
        } else {
            topMargin = statusBarHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Frame Layout is the solution.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all and doesn't explain why it even would.